# Assigning the name of the skins in the array into buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I have a code to randomize Skins

```
private var tiles:Array = [
            {"item":"Skin1", "chance":70 },
            {"item":"Skin2", "chance":5 },
            {"item":"Skin3", "chance":10 },
            {"item":"Skin4", "chance":10 },
            {"item":"Skin5", "chance":5 }
        ];


public function pickRandomByChance(options:Array):Object{
            var copy:Array=[];
            for (var i:int = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                  copy.push( { "item":options[i].item, "chance":options[i].chance } );
            }
            var range:Number = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < copy.length; i++){
                  range += copy[i].chance;
                  if (i > 0)
                  copy[i].chance += copy[i - 1].chance;
            }

            var pick:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * range);

            for (i = 0; i < copy.length; i++){
                 if (pick <= copy[i].chance)
                 return copy[i];
            }
    return null;
}
```

My question is how can i assign these skins to one of my buttons using setStyle?

```
button1.setStyle("skinClass", pickRandomByChance(tiles).item);
```

i tried to use the above code but i got an error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: I don't use the fl UI components really ever, but I don't think there is a "skinClass" property.   Try using "upSkin" or "overSkin" or "downSkin" or "selectedUpSkin" etc

Answer (score 0):

I think that your function is returning null (when setting they style its essentially calling null.item). I didn't test this code by I'm pretty sure it will work. Maybe give it a try. In my opinion, it's a little simpler.

```
public function pickRandomByChance(options:Array):Object{
    var weightedArray:Array = [];
    var range:Number = 0;
    for each(var tile:Object in options){
        for(var x = 0; x < tile.chance; x++){
            weightedArray.push(tile);
        }
        range += tile.chance;
    }
    return(weightedArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * range)].item);
}
```

EDIT: Now that I look at your skin array I think I found the error. Try the skin names without quotes:

```
var tiles:Array = [ {"item":Skin1, "chance":70 },
                    {"item":Skin2, "chance":5 },
                    {"item":Skin3, "chance":10 },
                    {"item":Skin4, "chance":10 },
                    {"item":Skin5, "chance":5 } 
                  ];
```

EDIT: See the revised return above and also apply the skin as shown below:

```
button1.setStyle("skinClass", pickRandomByChance(tiles));
```

Comment: The code does the same to which I've posted above but I still got the same error

Comment: When I pass the function to button1.setStyle("skinClass", pickRandomByChance(tiles).item); It gives me the same error but when i assign it to an object var picked:Object=pickRandomByChance(tiles); and pass the function to button1.setStyle("skinClass", picked.item); it worked fine. If i have many buttons do I need to create many objects just to get rid of the error or is there another way?

Comment: I revised the code block one more time. Make the pickRandomByChance function return the skin itself rather than the object and then drop the ".item" where you're applying the skin.

Comment: Got a new Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. It is pointing to the return statement.